# Get statistics on sent messages with Firebase Admin SDK for PHP

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to get statistics on sent messages. Found this [method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcmdata/rest/v1beta1/projects.androidApps.deliveryData/list) in the documentation, but the request was unsuccessful. Requires authentication.
[image: authentication required]
My team uses the [Firebase Admin SDK for PHP](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to send messages. I tried to find this method in the documentation, but did not find it.

Do have  Firebase Admin SDK for the PHP method to get statistics, maybe I just missed it?

Or probably can I authorize with Firebase Admin SDK for PHP, and send `GET https://fcmdata.googleapis.com/v1beta1/{parent=projects/*/androidApps/*}/deliveryData`  ?
[image]

Comment: It would be better if you posted actual text instead of an image.  How is someone supposed to copy it to their machine to try it out ?

Comment: This is an example from the documentation right on the front page of the Firebase Admin SDK for PHP, link in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the SDK you're using does not wrap the Google Analytics 4 Data API that you linked. There's nothing we can do here about it, so I recommend either filing a feature request on the [repo of that SDK](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/), or (even better) filing a pull request that adds the feature. :)